# Calculating $\mathbb P(X=Y)$ for any continouous distribution or $X,Y \sim$ Negbinomial using symmetry

Tags: probability, symmetry, exponential-distribution

Is it possible to calculate $\mathbb P(X=Y$) for continuous distribution such as $X,Y \sim\exp(\lambda)$, Negative binomial using symmetry

Using this calculation, we can calculate $\mathbb P(X<Y)$ and $\mathbb P(X\geq Y)$ by exchangeability?

Assume, $X,Y$ independent.

Comment: None of these probabilities can be calculated without independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the exponential case $P(X=Y)=0$ and $P (X<Y)=\frac  1 2$. This is true for any continuous distribution.

For negative Binomial distribution you have to calculate $P(X=Y)$ from the formula $P(X=Y)=\sum _n [P(X=n)]^{2}$. Once you do that you get $P(X<Y)=\frac 1 2 (1-P(X=Y))$. Of course, $P(X \geq Y)=P(X>Y)+P(X=Y)$.

Comment: I forgot to mention about the hypergeometric distribution. What is Pr(X=Y) for X,Y independent and $\sim$ Hyper?

Comment: For all discrete distributions you have to use  the formula $P(X=Y)=\sum P(X=n)^{2}$ and do some calculations. There is no short cut. @Numbers

Comment: What does $n$ stand for?

Comment: You have to sum over all $n$. For example, in the geometric case, $n$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$.  @Numbers